# How to label images in meteorJS application

Tags: image, meteor, tagging

I want to label images through your defined tags in meteor application.
I went through the following packages:
[yogiben](https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-autoform-file) & [meteor-simple-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) but was not able to find something concrete.

Additionally, meteor schema is using

> MySchema = new SimpleSchema({
>     firstName: {
>       type: String,
>       label: function () {
>         return Session.get("lang") == "de"
>               ? "Vorname" : "first name";
>       }
>     }
>   });

but I want the user to apply label dynamically.